# What is the format of training data in pyfann?

Tags: python, neural-network, fann

What is the format of thraining data in pyfann? Concretely I would like to use the init_weight function of pyfann, but it does not take a range, but finds the range from traning data. Therefore I would like to create a small fake dataset, which has the lowest and the highes value of what can be expected in the programm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frist Line, 3 arguments: number of data to train, number of inputs, number of outputs
from there, goes one line of inputs and one of outputs e.g. (AND logic matrix):

```
4 2 1    
1 1    
1    
0 1    
0    
0 0    
0    
1 0    
0
```

Above:

- 4 datas to train:

  1 AND 1 = 1
  0 AND 1 = 0
  0 AND 0 = 0
  1 AND 0 = 0
- 2 inputs
- 1 output

Answer (score 2):

Now you can also use `train_on_data`, which receives the same arguments as `train_on_file`, but you change the filename with an object `libfann.training_data()` and set the lists of lists of input and output as (for the xor case):

```
training = libfann.training_data()    
training.set_train_data([[-1,-1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[1,1]],[[-1],[1],[1],[-1]])
```