# Understanding FANN library's "fann_save" output file

Tags: c++, fann

I am training an artificial neural network in C++ using FANN library. I cannot understand/translate the syntax used to save neurons' weights in a text file through the function "fann_save()", in particular at section `connections (connected_to_neuron, weight)=` (the last one in the file).

What are the values printed referring to?

Comment: "... *the syntax used to save neurons' weights* ..." Neurons don't contain a weight property (only connections do).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the format of training data in pyfann?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063340/what-is-the-format-of-training-data-in-pyfann)

Answer (score 0):

there is no offcial documantation about it
means that written vaules not for user.
Library intenally use it for saving an loading of trained ANN
if you learn it you must examine source code

Answer (score -1):

> "... *what the values printed are referred to?*"

Line `connections` contains `connected_to_neuron` and `weight` (per connection). Position (order) defines originating neuron (as defined by `neurons (num_inputs, activation_function, activation_steepness)=`).

Consider using [fann_get_connection_array](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann-h.html#fann_get_connection_array) (or [fann_print_connections](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann-h.html#fann_print_connections)) instead.